# PhoneGap: replace static splash screen with HTML page

Tags: asynchronous, cordova, splash-screen

I'm building a [small cross-platform app](https://github.com/adamatan/cinema_sderot_phonegap_app) using PhoneGap. When I inspected the splash screen configuration, I found these attributes in `config.xml`:

```xml
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
```

It seems that the only splash screen allowed is a static image. I would like to use a dynamic splash screen which shows a spinner, makes a few network calls, and passes on to the main page when the calls return.

Any idea how to do this? I can disable the splash altogether and add this functionality to my inner web page, but it isn' elegant IMO.